# How to extract __VA_ARGS__?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, macros

I hava a macro to call static function for each args.

For example:

```
#define FOO(X) X::do();
#define FOO_1(X,Y) X::do(); Y::do();
```

My question is that I need to use foo with variable number of arguments, is it possible to use `__VA_ARGS__` ?

Like the line below:

```
#define FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__::do() ?
```

Thanks

Comment: In the future, if you could take just 5 seconds to look at the preview of your question, realize that the formatting is completely messed up, and then try to clean it up, that might make it a lot easier for people to answer. :) SO *does* feature code formatting capabilities. You just have to select the code, and press a button.

Comment: Use variadic templates instead...

Comment: Yeah,I used c++11 feature, in fact, I need a marco to define a function like this：
#define FOO(X) \
static void fooFunction() { \
X::do(); \ 
}

can I use variadic templates instead ? 

Thanks

Comment: @Kennir: You can. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro expansion does not work like argument pack expansion with variadic templates. What you have will expand to:

```
X,Y::do();
```

And not to

```
X::do(); Y::do();
```

As you hoped. But in C++11 you could use variadic templates. For instance, you could do what you want this way:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X { static void foo() { std::cout << "X::foo()" << std::endl; }; };
struct Y { static void foo() { std::cout << "Y::foo()" << std::endl; }; };
struct Z { static void foo() { std::cout << "Z::foo()" << std::endl; }; };

int main()
{
    do_foo<X, Y, Z>();
}
```

All you need is this (relatively simple) machinery:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    struct do_foo;

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct do_foo<T, Ts...>
    {
        static void call()
        {
            T::foo();
            do_foo<Ts...>::call();
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct do_foo<T>
    {
        static void call()
        {
            T::foo();
        }
    };
}

template<typename... Ts>
void do_foo()
{
    detail::do_foo<Ts...>::call();
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/zBBuTf).

Comment: btw: why there need three functions with different template arguments?

Comment: @Kennir: I'm not sure I understand your question. What arguments?

Comment: sorry for my poor english.

    template <typename... Ts>
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    template<typename T>

why there need 3 types of template?

Comment: @Kennir: OK, so first of all those are not "arguments", but class templates. The first one is the *primary template*, while the next two are *specializations* of that primary template. You may want to read about template specialization a bit, or ask a further question on SO - the topic is too broad to be answered in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly, `__VA_ARGS__` is always treated as a single unit consisting of all the parameters separated by a comma. The preprocessor provides no built-in way to find the number of parameters, to separate them or to loop over them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11920694/431526) to a similar question shows the basic solution using the preprocessor: Find out how many items there are in your argument list and pass it on to a macro that does take this exact amount of parameters.

I’d recommend not to do this but instead use [Andy Prowls C++11 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372879/431526) or even restructure your code so you don’t need this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can partially workaround this.
You can directly and freely extract every member of neither `__VA_ARGS__` nor variadic templates of C++11. But you can have the very first element. For example let's say we have a macro named `OUT(...)` and we want to produce std::cout << A << B << C ... where A, B, C are the variadic arguments of macro. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SEPERATOR <<
#define GET_1_OF(element1, ...) element1
#define GET_2_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_1_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define GET_3_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_2_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define BAR(...) GET_3_OF(__VA_ARGS__)
int main()
{
    std::cout << BAR(1,2,3,4,5);
    return 0;
}
```

This is of course not the solution you are after. But you can augment the number of GET_N_OF to do what you want. Note that `SEPERATOR` is `<<` so that we MACRO can write  `1 << 2 << 3` and so on.
Now, we have a problem in this code. Please change `BAR(1,2,3,4,5)` with `BAR(1)` You will see that it is giving an error. This is because it was expecting 3 arguments, although it is not problem to have more arguments (because it is variadic) we are having extra  `SEPERATOR`. So in order to solve this problem instead of using `BAR(...)` use `GET_N_OF(...)` (since you know the number of arguments):

```
#include <iostream>

#define SEPERATOR <<
#define GET_1_OF(element1, ...) element1
#define GET_2_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_1_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define GET_3_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_2_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define GET_4_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_3_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define GET_5_OF(element1, ...) element1 SEPERATOR GET_4_OF(__VA_ARGS__) 

int main()
{
    std::cout << GET_5_OF(1,2,3,4,5);
    std::cout << GET_1_OF(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that **if you do not know what you are doing** do not use MACROs at all! My response was just to share fun MACRO code that may be beneficial for you. I always discourage the usage of MACROs until they are remarkably necessary.