# c++ (MSVC) __VA_ARGS__ macro element by element, into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, macros, variadic

```
#define enumDEF(ename,...) enum ename{__VA_ARGS__}; \
    const int _int_##ename []={__VA_ARGS__};\
    char _str_##ename[]={ #__VA_ARGS__ };\
    int _cnt_##ename =sizeof(_int_##ename)/sizeof(int);
 
    enumDEF(DAYS, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)

 DAYS nnn = Monday;
 int count = _cnt_DAYS;
```

Count is ok.
But:
_str_DAYS="Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday"

I need, all item by array. Like this
_str_DAYS[0]="Monday"
_str_DAYS[1]="Tuesday"

_str_DAYS[6]="Sunday"

Possible?

Comment: See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11920577/3740047) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479282/3740047) post.

Comment: thx. but-
I don't want such a solution.
I don't like that I have to enter every variation, the number of parameters.
In 1984, the MASM compiler already knew this well. :-)

Comment: Well, you could also use existing libraries. E.g. [magic enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum), which apparently does not require any boilerplate code. Otherwise, also check the list [here](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#reflection).